# Reset NSLayoutConstraint constant to its original value from the Storyboard

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint

Imagine the scenario where you have laid out a `UIView` with an `NSLayoutConstraint` that has different `constant`s for several of the size classes in your Storyboard. Now you want to animate the position of this view by modifying that constraint's `constant`. Let's say you want to animate it from -100 to its original value that you set in the storyboard for the current size class. How can you get that value to use in the animation code?

That way you wouldn't have to detect the size class in code and set it all programmatically with the values that align with what was already set in the Storyboard.

Comment: did you come up with any solution for this?

Comment: @MichaelJohnston I didn't

Answer (score 1):

1) create an outlet for your constraint

2) in the condition when you want to animate the constraint change constraint.constant value to the value you want to set

3) In your animation block call view.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

Connect your layout constraint to an outlet in Interface Builder.  Then when your view is loaded, cache the value of [`constraint.constant`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSLayoutConstraint/constant) in an ivar.  Then you can change it and reset it however you wish.

Comment: That would work if you didn't change the `constant` value for different size classes. But what if for Any w Any h you set it to 20 and for Any w Compact h 10, then the user launched the app on an iPhone in portrait and then rotated to landscape? The cached value is now incorrect and you'd be placing the view in the incorrect location for the current size class.

Comment: You can re-cache the value when the orientation changes.

Comment: That's what I'm attempting to prevent. The value is already defined in the storyboard, I don't want to redefine every value for every constraint for every size class and risk inconsistencies. Also, note that size classes can change without a rotation occurring.

Comment: This is what I decided to do, never had a need for more than one or two per class.  I may have looked harder if I had to worry about every single value.  I guess you could try to read it directly from the storyboard?